# CORS does not work for login user for POST, PUT, DELETE in Blazor WASM after deploy on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, cors, blazor-webassembly

I am using a Blazor WebAssembly application as the frontend and a standard C# REST API as the backend. I am encountering difficulties with configuring CORS for the Blazor WASM application. The CORS configuration functions correctly when a user is not logged in. However, when a user is logged in, all endpoints that employ HTTP methods such as POST, PUT, and DELETE result in a 405 Method Not Allowed error. The most bizarre aspects of this issue is that everything functions seamlessly on my local development machine. However, upon deployment to an IIS server running on Windows Server, the problem surfaces.

Here is preflight for request without log-in user
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8Jqe.png)

Here is preflight when user is log-in
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n50Wk.png)

And final error
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFgoI.png)

Here is my CORS configuration on backend looks like this

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var corsSettings = builder.Configuration.GetSection(CorsSettings.SectionName).Get<CorsSettings>();
ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(corsSettings, nameof(corsSettings));
builder.Services.AddCorsPolicy(corsSettings);

[...]

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AuthDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthDbContext>();

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.Name = "GlossaryAuthCookie";
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
    
    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(ClaimsNames.IsAdmin, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimsNames.IsAdmin, ClaimsValues.True));
    options.AddPolicy(ClaimsNames.IsEditor, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimsNames.IsEditor, ClaimsValues.True));
    options.AddPolicy(ClaimsNames.IsActive, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimsNames.IsActive, ClaimsValues.True));
});

[...]

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors(corsSettings.PolicyName);

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapGet("/", () => "PW Glossary API");

app.Run();
```

My AddCorsPolicy extension is nothing out of ordinary

```
serviceCollection.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(corsSettings.PolicyName, policyBuilder =>
    {
        policyBuilder.AllowCredentials();

        if (corsSettings.AllowedHeaders.All(x => x.Equals("*")))
            policyBuilder.AllowAnyHeader();
        else
            policyBuilder.WithHeaders(corsSettings.AllowedHeaders);
        
        if (corsSettings.AllowedMethods.All(x => x.Equals("*")))
            policyBuilder.AllowAnyMethod();
        else
            policyBuilder.WithMethods(corsSettings.AllowedMethods);
        
        if (corsSettings.AllowedOrigins.All(x => x.Equals("*")))
            policyBuilder.AllowAnyOrigin();
        else
            policyBuilder.WithOrigins(corsSettings.AllowedOrigins);
        
    });
});
```

At the Blazor Wasm side I have following configuration

```
builder.Services.AddRefitClient<IBackendApi>()
    .ConfigureHttpClient(httpClient => httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(backendUrl))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<CookieHandler>();
```

CookieHandler

```
public class CookieHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> 
        SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.SetBrowserRequestMode(BrowserRequestMode.Cors);
        request.SetBrowserRequestCredentials(BrowserRequestCredentials.Include);

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

And example of Refit endopint

```
[Put("/api/glossary/")]
Task<ApiResponse<UpdateGlossaryEntryResponse>> UpdateGlossaryEntryAsync([Body] UpdateGlossaryEntryRequest request);
```

I have also try on different browser (Chrome, Edge, Firefox) and on different machines to be sure that it does not cache some olde configuration.

Comment: If you didn’t install and configure IIS Cors module, now it is the time.

Comment: Your project should be using Core 7.0.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=maui

Comment: @LexLi I definitely forgot about that unfortunately, it did not help but I will try to ticker a little bit more in configuration and see where it goes.

Comment: @jdweng I have already implemented `class GlossaryAuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider`. Acording to documentation that you priveded it does not seems like someting is missing. Key difference is that I registered it with add scope and in documentation there is TryAddScope and AddSingleton, so I will see how it affect my solution.

Comment: Can you debug backend?  Add break points or debug messages to see where code is actually going.  The connection is completing since GET is working and you are getting a response status code.  It looks like it is working without credentials which means the IIS server is not in same domain as the client.  Both client and server need to use the same password server to validate the credentials.  Authentication is working which occurs before the credentials are checked.

Comment: @jdweng both frontend and backend are hosted on the same IIS server only on different ports. I could try (once more) to set some rewrite rules so the backend and frontend would appear at the same port. The previous attempt failed but I do not remember what was an issue. I am not entirely sure how it be finally hosted on production, so I try to keep the front and back as separate hosts. At the moment I am so desperate that I decided to switch from cookie authentication to jwt just to see if the problem persists.

Comment: There is three different apps working together 1) the client code 2) The service 3) The database.  The service (2nd app) has a two ports A) Client to Server(front end) B) Server to database (backend).  The error is occurring in the service on the front end interface with the client.   Blazor is the interface used on the front end in both client and server.  Rest is the interface in the service backend and the database.

Comment: When you switched from cookie authentication to jwt, does the problem still exist?